# pass arguments to an event handler

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a bootstrapped button generated in meteor from reactive-tables package (a delete document button):

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-docid="kmDk4qQBwLpbXPDdA"></span></button>`

In the interest of keeping logic separate from html, I need to fetch the key in data-docid node and then delete the document. I was going to get this through event.target.innerHTML and parse the contents, however if a user clicks on the *button* element all is good, but if the mouse pointer moves to the actual *glyphicon-trash span* and the user clicks on that, innerHTML is empty.

Can anyone recommend how to target the button and fetch data-docid node so it works every time? Or is there another place I can pass the data-docid key to a function through an event handler?

Comment: You need to use `$(event.target).data('docid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Meteor gives you jQuery, so you might use it to simplify dealing with DOM.

The `data-docid` parameter belongs logically to the `button` element, there's no need to move it down to `span`.

<strike>Since as you've mentioned the `e.target` can be an element *inside* of your button, you need to find the button first before you fetch the data. So the actual line will be:</strike>

```
$(e.target).closest('button').data('docid');
```

Since as you've mentioned the `e.target` can be an element *inside* of your button, you can use `currentTarget` instead to fetch the element you've attached the handler to. So the updated line will be:

```
$(e.currentTarget).data('docid');
```

Also take a note that `this` context inside you event handler is the same as Handlebars data context around the button. So if you actually generate the `docid` value from data, you can access it as well via `this` keyword in the handler.

Comment: Why not listen for events on the button and use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`?

Comment: Right, that's an even better idea.